# custom image on UINavigationBar for iOS < 5.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I am using a "defensive" code to set a custom image to UINavigationBar bar - it works well on devices with ios5 or later.

After some answers, I am editing the code with a combined answer (see below)

**Is this is right & elegant way to do this?**

```
if ([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {
        UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableTitleView.png"];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
    else
    {

        NSString *barBgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"tableTitleView" ofType:@"png"];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer setContents:(id)[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: barBgPath].CGImage];
    }
```

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499259/navigation-controller-not-working-properly/10582222#10582222) link . I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float version = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
        NSLog(@"%f",version);
        if (version >= 5.0) {
            UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Myimage.png"];
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        }
        else
        {

            NSString *barBgPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Myimage" ofType:@"png"];
            [self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer setContents:(id)[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: barBgPath].CGImage];
        }
```

Maybe it will help you. it works for me.

Comment: It's beter to use the `respondsToSelector:` to check if a feature is available. You should not just check the version. If Apple changes the methode name or the version is presented differently you code will break.

Comment: @rckoenes ty for the info . m new to this and this works for me so i dnt knw .. thanks for the great info dude...

Comment: Thanks Chinttu and rckoenes, I have changed the question above that combines both answers, assuming this is acceptable to other gurus I will except Chinttu answer.

Comment: @ShiShi n e time buddy. happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method :-

```
#define kSCNavBarImageTag 6183746
#define kSCNavBarColor [UIColor colorWithRed:0.54 green:0.18 blue:0.03 alpha:1.0]


+ (void)customizeNavigationController:(UINavigationController *)navController
{
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [navController navigationBar];
    [navBar setTintColor:kSCNavBarColor];

    if ([navBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
    {
        [navBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar-bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[navBar viewWithTag:kSCNavBarImageTag];
        if (imageView == nil)
        {
            imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation-bar-bg.png"]];
            [imageView setTag:kSCNavBarImageTag];
            [navBar insertSubview:imageView atIndex:0];
            [imageView release];
        }
    }
}
```

it will work on both ios 4 and 5 the if ..else block is for the same.

There is a good [NavIMage tutorial](http://sebastiancelis.com/2009/12/21/addingbackground-image-uinavigationbar/)